# CSS incompetent - cannot figure out why my page is rendering the way it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

To preface, I am utterly incompetent with CSS. However, I have been watching/reading tutorials, and still cannot figure out why my page would render the way it is. I'm hoping that this will be quick and obvious for somebody here.

I want the page to be shaped something like this:

> Filter by:   CPM Owner: [DROPDOWN]   CP: [DROPDOWN]   Series: [DROPDOWN]
>
> [APPROVE SELECTED] [REJECT SELECTED]
>
> [there's a table down here, but it isn't relevant to the question]

However, it looks like this when I load the page:

[image]

EDIT: I changed the flexbox container to a span instead of a div, and now the page looks like:

[image]

There are all kinds of newlines I don't want, and strange spacing being put before the dropdowns. Here are the relevant bits of CSS, JS, and HTML that are making this part of the page:

HTML:

```
<div id="filters">
    <span id="filter_dropdowns_label" class="dropdowns_bar_label">
        Filter by:
    </span>
    <ul id="filter_dropdowns" class="dropdowns_bar">
        <!-- populated by changerequest.js -->
    </ul>
</div>
<ul id="buttons_top" class="buttons">
    <li><input type="button" value="Approve Selected" id="approve_button_top" class="approve_button" onclick="approveSelected()"/></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="Reject Selected" id="reject_button_top" class="reject_button" onclick="rejectSelected()"/></li> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdowns_bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdowns_bar li {
    display: inline;
}

.buttons li {
    display: inline;
}

.hidden_column {
    display: none;
}

#filters {
     display: inline;
}
```

And the JS:

```
// Create a dropdown
function createDropdown(id, label, data, defaultValue) {
    // initialize elements
    listEl = document.createElement('li');
    flexboxContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
    spanEl = document.createElement('span');

    // setup dropdown
    $(flexboxContainerEl).flexbox(data);
    $(flexboxContainerEl).attr('id', id);
    if (defaultValue != null) {
    $(flexboxContainerEl).setValue(defaultValue);    
    }

    // setup label
    $(spanEl).html(label + ':');

    // add to document
    $(listEl).append(spanEl);
    $(listEl).append(flexboxContainerEl);
    $('#filter_dropdowns').append(listEl);
}

// Creates and populates the filter dropdowns, selects default if present
function createDropdowns() {
    createDropdown('cpm_dropdown', 'CPM Owner', cpmList, cpmDefault);
    createDropdown('cp_dropdown', 'CP', cpList, cpDefault);
    createDropdown('series_dropdown', 'Series', seriesList, seriesDefault);
}
```

Sorry, I realize that this question is very much "help, my code's broken, fix it." I am just spending a lot of time looking at CSS tutorials and documents and I cannot find anything resembling my problem.

---

EDIT: Modified my CSS according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17417451/1532702

The page now looks like:

[image]

I've tried swapping the `.append`s, but nothing affects the order on the labels. Obviously, they should be in front of each of the corresponding inputs.

---

EDIT: I solved my problem by just rewriting that portion as a table instead of a list. Made everything much, much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, better answer I think. Try this:

```
.dropdowns_bar li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.buttons {
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.buttons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the question again, I'm actually thinking inline-block rather than floats would work best here.

Comment: @RyanCoonan To move the labels in front, change 'append()' to 'prepend()'

Comment: Neither changing the appends to prepends, nor swapping the order in which the elements are added has had any effect on the look of the page.